# discord.py get embed image url and check if it exists in json file

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, bots

so as the title says i'm trying to check if a message.embeds[0].image.url exists inside my json file, this is my code

```
import discord
import json
from datetime import datetime

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = commands.when_mentioned_or('n.')
js = open("file.json","r")
data= json.load(js)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is online') 

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.embeds) == 0:
         return
    elif message.embeds[0].image.url in data["group"]:
         embed=discord.Embed(message.embeds[0].color)
         embed.add_field(name="Server", value=message.server)
         embed.add_field(name="Channel", value=message.channel)
         embed.add_field(name="Time", value=datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S on %x'))
         embed.set_image(url=message.embeds[0].image.url)
         channel = bot.get_channel(854710154045292565)
         await channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
         return

bot.run('token')
```

and this is how my json file is like

```
{
    "group":
    [
    {
    "subgroup1":["url1","url2","url3","url4","url5"],
    "subgroup2":["url1","url2","url3","url4","url5"],
    "subgroup3":["url1","url2","url3","url4","url5"],
     ...
    "subgroupX":["url1","url2","url3","url4","url5"]
    }
    ]
}
```

i tried testing it with urls that i already had in my json file and it seems to work even though i'm not sure, but the problem is that the bot keeps sending the embedded message infinite times until it's closed.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because it reacts to its own messages. To prevent `on_message` from executing when the message author is the bot itself you can add simple if statement on the start of event. Like this:

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
```